# javascript to get substring of recordNumber

Tags: javascript

I have a string as below and i wanted to extract the `recordNumber` value. For ex: i need to extract the value like  `PTL-HPCAN-2022-00157`

```
{"Request":"{\"header\":{\"action\":\"SubmitRecordAndCalculateFees\",\"username\":\"PUBLICUSER\",\"trxId\":\"2c348091-3f1c-4ccb-b854-92cd5d164565\",\"language\":\"EN\"},\"body\":{\"recordNumber\":\"PTL-HPCAN-2022-00157\"}}"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code:

```
var inputString = {"Request":"{\"header\":{\"action\":\"SubmitRecordAndCalculateFees\",\"username\":\"PUBLICUSER\",\"trxId\":\"2c348091-3f1c-4ccb-b854-92cd5d164565\",\"language\":\"EN\"},\"body\":{\"recordNumber\":\"PTL-HPCAN-2022-00157\"}}"}

console.log(JSON.parse(inputString.Request).body.recordNumber)
```

Comment: Also any idea for extracting recordNumber for below string {"Response":{"status":"200","result":{"result":{"Success":true,"Message":"","ErrorCode":null},"data":{"recordId":"22CAP-00000-000YG","recordNumber":"RSLC-2022-00000034","recordBalance":"0.0","recordFees":null}}}}

Comment: `console.log(inputString.Response.result.data.recordNumber)`

Answer (score 0):

Your string seems to be an invalid string, please check the below code on how to extract the desired output!

```js
const str = "{\"header\":{\"action\":\"SubmitRecordAndCalculateFees\",\"username\":\"PUBLICUSER\",\"trxId\":\"2c348091-3f1c-4ccb-b854-92cd5d164565\",\"language\":\"EN\"},\"body\":{\"recordNumber\":\"PTL-HPCAN-2022-00157\"}}";

const obj = JSON.parse(str);

console.log(obj.body.recordNumber);
```